# How to open a popup windows and cause a full postback in the parent window after closing the popoup?

Tags: asp.net

In asp.net, I want to click on a button to open a popup windows. after the popup windows, I want to cause a full postback to the parent window.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On your popup write the below script:

```
window.opener.PostBack(); 
// Where PostBack is the custom method of opener/parent window.
```

Either you can do it in `OnUnload()` event of your popup or from any other method followed by `window.close();`.

You can implement the `PostBack()` method like this in opener:

```
        function PostBack() {
            var btn = document.getElementById('<%=SomeButton.ClientID %>');
            if (btn) btn.click();
            // or
            // __doPostBack('SomeButtonId','Arguments');
        }
```

Comment: is the PostBack() function available for opener?

Comment: inside PostBack() method, how can I raise a full refresh for the parent page?

Comment: Sorry...I didn't get what you mean by full refresh. AFAIK, when you do  `postback` a whole page life cycle happens.

Comment: yes, each PostBack initiates the [Page Life Cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

Comment: I added the PostBack function in the parent opener page with alert('raised') but the parent page does not show the alert message?

Comment: could you please help me with that?

Comment: I've created a [sample application](http://www.filedropper.com/postback), please check it. Hope this helps.